# Insert text above <input type="image">

Tags: html, css, webshop

The below code is for adding a product to the basket.

Instead of just using an image as a buy button in the input, I would like to have an image or a fill in the background and HTML text above it.

```
<input border="0" src="/images/buy.png" type="image" />
```

This is the complete code:

```
<span class="BuyButton_ProductInfo">
    <table id="BUYSECTION">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left">Count<br />
                    <input id="amount" class="TextInputField_ProductInfo" maxlength="6" size="3" name="AMOUNT" value="1" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="BuyButton_ProductInfo">Buy<br />
                    <input border="0" src="/images/buy.png" type="image" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</span>
```

Comment: What about a `<button>` element? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XcrKM/

Answer (score 1):

You can insert text above input elements. I'm use **label** element for this work. You can edit the label element position with using CSS codes.

```html
<input src="/images/buy.png" type="image" id="myButton" />
<label for="myButton">Click me or image</label>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. He wants to have an image in the background and text in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely what you are trying to accomplish? Can you just set the `display` property in CSS?

```
#BUYSECTION input[type="image"] {  
  display:block;
}
```

Otherwise, can you elaborate? Maybe provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link to show the issue?

**EDITED**

Is it that you want a clickable submit button, with a pattern or "button-like" fill, but to still have text at a different z-index "above" the button?

HTML:

```
<button type="submit">Buy</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  /* reset the button style properties */
  border:0;
  display:block;
  /* include the image and dimensions */
  width:50px;
  height: 20px;
  background:transparent url("images/buy.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  /* format the text */
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#333;
}
```

Comment: The other alternative would be to position one or both absolutely, but this might have unexpected consequences when it came time to fire the click event on the button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

What I need exactly is: instead of an image where the text is a part of the image button.

I want to put an image, and HTML text above it.

Comment: Then the above markup and styling should do the trick. The text between the <button>...</button> will display, and the background will be rendered using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly either,

But if you're talking about a solid background color on the submit button, you can use

```
<input type="submit" style="background-color: black; color: white;" value="your text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Texto del boton" class="imgButton" />​
```

CSS:

```
.imgButton{
background-image:url(/images/buy.png);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;    
}​
```

Saludos!